# How can I use more than one value in my select options to sort a UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-lists, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple `<select>` dropdowns to filter a UL by different data-attributes, but within my `<select>` I have a data-attribute value that applies to more than one of my options. So how can I get one `<option>` represent two values?

Here is what I currently have, its in a table for style reasons. And when you select value "nominee" I want it to show both the "winner" and "nominee" values since if you win something you were technically also a nominee:

HTML:

```js
$('.category').on('change', function() {
  category_filters = [];

 $('.search-filters select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 0) {
      category_filters[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    }
  });

  $("#episode-list .result").hide().filter(function() { 
    var show = true;
    for (var category in category_filters) {
       show = show && $(this).data(category) == category_filters[category];
    }
    
    return show;
  }).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="search-filters"">
          <tr class="filter-block">
            <td><p>Best Picture</p>
              <select id="filterbp" class="category">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="winner">Best Picture Winners</option>
                <option value="nominee">Best Picture Nominees</option>
                <option value="none">Non-Best Picture Nominees</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><p>Best Director</p>
              <select id="filterdirector" class="category">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="winner">Best Director Winners</option>
                <option value="nominee">Best Director Nominees</option>
                <option value="none">Non-Best Director Nominees</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
</table>

<ul id="episode-list">
<li data-filterbp="winner" data-filterdirector="winner" class="result">BPwin DIRwin</li>
<li data-filterbp="nominee" data-filterdirector="nominee" class="result">BPnom DIRnom</li>
<li data-filterbp="none" data-filterdirector="none" class="result">BPnone DIRnone</li>
<li data-filterbp="nominee" data-filterdirector="none" class="result">BPnom DIRnone</li>
<li data-filterbp="winner" data-filterdirector="nominee" class="result">BPwin DIRnom</li>
<li data-filterbp="nominee" data-filterdirector="nominee" class="result">BPnom DIRnom</li>
<li data-filterbp="none" data-filterdirector="none" class="result">BPnone DIRnone</li>
<li data-filterbp="nominee" data-filterdirector="winner" class="result">BPnom DIRwin</li>
<li data-filterbp="none" data-filterdirector="nominee" class="result">BPnone DIRnom</li>
<li data-filterbp="winner" data-filterdirector="winner" class="result">BPwin DIRwin</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your `show` boolean will only be dependent on last iteration of the `for` loop since each iteration overwrites the previous one. Still not 100% clear what the filtering rules are

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem but it appears that you have two choices: 
1. Work out a scheme by which data attributes fully describe the data.
2. Include special cases into the javascript that performs the filtering.

Comment: When selecting the "none" option I want it to filter and show the <li> for the selected data-attribute value of "none", same thing for the value of "winner" (both of these are working right now). But when selecting the value "nominee" I want it to filter and show the <li> with data values of both "winner" & "nominee"

Sorry I wasn't clear before.